# RMarkdown plots in Beamer slides produce -.bb text above figure

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, beamer

For some reason, when I knit to Beamer PDF slides in R Markdown, figures show up with the chunk name and .bb in text written above them on the slides. I've given an example of my code for a slide and a screencap of the output.

I don't have any knitr chunk options set in the document other than making plots transparent.

I have found that removing the chunk name makes the text go away, but ideally I'd like to keep naming my chunks for future reference. I just don't understand what's causing the text and would appreciate any insight!

Chunk to create the plot:

````
```{r discrete pdf}
crashes<-c(0,1,2,3,4)
prob<-c(0.8,0.1,0.06,0.03,0.01)
crashes<-data.frame(crashes, prob)

crashes.pdf<-ggplot(crashes, aes(x=crashes, y=prob))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#0072B2")+xlab("Crashes")+ylab("Probability")
```
````

Chunk calling the plot and posting to slides:

````
```{r discrete pdf show, echo=FALSE,fig.height=4.5, warning=FALSE}
crashes.pdf
```
````

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ngpI.png) is below:

[image]

Comment: I can't really reproduce your issue, because the code example you give does not print the code chunk name above the plot when I run it in a fresh RMarkdown beamer document . However, I believe the code chunk name cannot contain spaces. Try changing your code chunk name to  `discrete_pdf_show`.

Comment: Removing spaces did the trick! Just a bad habit I must have forgotten when naming them, thanks!